# Polygon geofencing with iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I am trying to find a way to create several polygon geofences with iOS. I need to draw multiple zones in a city to represent areas, streets, etc. From what I've read so far, iOS only allows circular zone from a geolocated device.

1. Is it feasible with iOS?
2. Is there a web app somewhere to draw polygons on a map and generate the coordinates in an array?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) iOS only allows to create circular geofences indeed however what you are trying to achieve is possible with some extra logic.
I have developed similar features so I suggest you to do the following:

- create a circular geofence that embeds your polygon
- when the device gets notified as being within the circular geofence,
  start the GPS
- every time you get a location update, check if its coordinates are
     within the polygon
- turn off the GPS as soon as the device's location is found within the
  polygon, unless you need to be notified when exiting the polygon as
  well
- turn off the GPS when the device gets notified as outside the
  circular geofence

As you need polygon geofences I guess you expect a good level of accuracy, so you would need to use an extra layer of GPS on top of the geofencing anyways, as geofencing is not accurate at all.

2) Have a look at those links:

- https://github.com/thedilab/v3-polygon-shape-creator
- https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

Comment: Thanks Laurent, it is much appreciated and this is a good approach. Have you got a Github by any chance?

Comment: No I don't. Please accept my answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: If a polygon is embedded within another polygon, would that approach still work? Because creating a circular geofence would overflow to the next polygon within wouldn't it?

Comment: This approach would still work. But be careful, there is a limited number of geofences you can monitor at a time (about 10), so you need to optimise them. For example, you can create only one geofence for multiple embedded polygon.

Comment: Thanks Laurent, i really appreciate this approach. I used this approach and achieved my requirement when the app is in foreground/background, but not when the app is killed/terminated state. I think it was due to the default 10 seconds of time that iOS wakes up the system and again put it to sleep/kill it. beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:) also will extend time to 3 minutes if am not wrong. I need to extend the time until the user gets into the polygon and getting out. Any help on this is appreciable. Thanks!