# How to create a circular geofence area that embeds your polygon for geofencing?

Tags: ios, geofencing

I am trying the best way to implement Polygon Geofencing for IOS. I have referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789341/polygon-geofencing-with-ios)

I am trying the first approach. I want some help in code to implement that approach.

With the polygon coordinates how to create a circular geofenced area?
Is there any algorithm to create a circular area embedding polygon coordinates?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck getting the algorithm on the Mathematics StackExchange website: https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is called `The Smallest Circle` problem.

Essentially, you are looking for the smallest circle that contains a list of points.

A bit of googling finds that it can be done in linear time.

The algorithm is described thusly...

> The algorithm processes the points of S in a random order, maintaining as it does the set P of processed points and the smallest circle that encloses the union of P and Q. At each step, it tests whether the next point r to be processed belongs to this circle; if it does not, the algorithm replaces the enclosing circle by the result of a recursive call of the algorithm on the sets P and Q+r. Whether the circle was replaced or not, r is then included in the set P. Processing each point, therefore, consists of testing in constant time whether the point belongs to a single circle and possibly performing a recursive call to the algorithm. It can be shown that the ith point to be processed has probability 
>   O
>   (
>   1
>   /
>   i
>   )
>   O(1/i) of generating a recursive call, and therefore that the overall time is linear.

[Here is the Wikipedia link about the problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)

You can probably find lots more resources about this problem from here.

Hope that helps.

[Here is another site that possibly provides a more complete solution](https://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle)